# Finding the limit of a recursive sequence.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

> Let $a_n \in \Bbb{R}$ such that: $$ a_{n+1}=1+\frac{2}{a_n}  \text{  and   } a_1=1$$
>
> Prove that $\lim_{n \to +\infty}a_n=2$

We have that $a_n \geq 1,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}$ thus $$\limsup_na_n \geq \liminf_na_n \geq 1$$

Let $\liminf_na_n=l$

Then we have that $l^2-l-2=0$ thus $l=2,-1$

But $a_n \geq 1$ thus $l=2$.

Applying the same argument we prove that $\limsup_na_n=2$

Also we can also derive a contradiction if we assume that the limit superior and inferior are infinite.

Is my attempt an efficient way to prove this statement?

Also can someone provide additional solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: define $b_n = \frac{a_n-2}{a_n+1}$ and show that it satisfies $b_{n+1} = -\frac12 b_n$. use this to deduce a closed form expression of $a_n$.

Comment: @achillehui...is my way correct..i will try your hint...Also is there any textbook for  attacking and solving problems with recursive sequences?

Comment: Your argument won't work. Unlike limit, $\liminf a_n = \ell$ doesn't implies $\liminf(1 + \frac{2}{a_n}) = 1 + \frac{2}{\ell}$ directly (even when you assume $a_n > 0$). However for positive numbers $c_n$ bounded away from zero and infinity, we have
$$\liminf \frac{1}{c_n} = \frac{1}{\limsup c_n}\quad\text{ and }\quad \limsup \frac{1}{c_n} = \frac{1}{\liminf c_n}$$ If $\limsup a_n = u$, then you can deduce from $a_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{2}{a_n}$ the consequence $$\ell = 1 + \frac{2}{u}\;\text{ and }\; u = 1 + \frac{2}{\ell} \implies (\ell-2)(\ell+1) = 0 \implies \ell = 2$$

Comment: @achillehui...you are right..i had tottaly forgotten the two relations with limsup and liminf you mention..how can we overcome hte possibilty that the sequence is unbounded without finding an explicit formula?

Comment: The map $x \mapsto 1 + \frac{2}{x}$ send $(0,\infty)$ to $(1,\infty)$, the next iteration send it to $(1,3)$. If you start from any $a_1 \in (0,\infty)$, you have $a_n \in (1,3)$ for all $n > 2$.

Comment: Please note that while the title is about "finding" a limit, the actual question is about "verifying" a limit. The latter is often easier than the former because you can simply use the definition of limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Banach's Fixed Point theorem also provides the limit.
It states that the iteration $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ will converge to  $a^* = f(a^*)$ if $|f'(a)| <1$ during  the iteration.

Now $|f'(a)| = 2/a^2$ which in general will not be less than one. Taking two iteration steps however gives

$$
a_{n+2} = g(a_n) = 3 - \frac{4}{a_n+2}
$$

and $|g'(a)| = \frac{4}{(a+2)^2}$ which is less than one for all $a_n >0$, which will always be the case over the iteration.

Answer (score 6):

Here we have where $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ where
$$f(x)=1+\frac2x=\frac{x+2}{x}.$$
Maps of the form $x\mapsto (ax+b)/(cx+d)$ are *fractional linear transformations* and can be represented by matrices. If we let $A=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ and define
$$A\bullet x=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$
then $A\bullet (B\bullet x)=AB\bullet x$.

Here take $A=\pmatrix{1&2\\1&0}$. Then $a_{n+1}=A^n\bullet1$. We can diagonalise $A$:
$$A=\pmatrix{1&2\\-1&1}\pmatrix{-1&0\\0&2}\pmatrix{1&2\\-1&1}^{-1}$$
and so
$$A^{n-1}=\pmatrix{1&2\\-1&1}\pmatrix{(-1)^n&0\\0&2^n}
\pmatrix{1&2\\-1&1}^{-1}.$$
Now it is straightforward to calculate Dr Graubner's formula.

Answer (score 2):

an explicit formula is given by $$a_n=-\frac{2+\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n}{-1+\left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^n}$$ so $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=2$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

- $a_n \ge 2 \implies a_{n+2} \ge 2, \ a_{n+2} \le a_n$
- $a_n \le 2 \implies a_{n+2} \le 2, \ a_{n+2} \ge a_n$
- $ 1 = a_1 \le a_3 \le a_5 \le \cdots \le 2 \le \cdots \le a_6 \le a_4 \le a_2 =3 $

Answer (score 2):

$a_{n+2}-a_n=\frac{4(a_n-a_{n-2})}{(a_n+2)(a_{n-2}+2)}  - ①$

We can confirm the sign of $a_{n+2}-a_{n}$ and that of $a_{n}-a_{n-2}$ are same from ①. 
For $a_1 < a_3$ and $a_4<a_2$, we can say $a_{2m-1} < a_{2m+1}$ and $a_{2m+2}<a_{2m}$ respectively. 
Thus, $a_1<a_3<…<a_{2m-1}<…<2$, $a_2>a_4>…>a_{2m>}…>2$
$\{a_{2m-1}\}$ has upper bound and let $\alpha$ be its limit value. Also, $\{a_{2m}\}$ has lower bound and let $\beta$ be its limit value. 
We can gain $\beta=1+\frac{2}{\alpha}-②$ and $\alpha=1+\frac{2}{\beta}-③$ from $a_{2m}=1+\frac{2}{a_{2m-1}}, a_{2m+1}=1+\frac{2}{a_{2m}}(m\rightarrow\infty)$
Finally, we can get $\alpha=\beta=2$ from ② and ③. This completes the proof.